# Error in integrate: non-finite function value

Tags: r, integration

f_heston is used in the definition of f_2, which is again used in the g_heston function. I need to integrate g_heston from 0 to infinity.

```
f_heston=function(u,r,q,tau,V0,S0,sigma,rho,kappa,theta){
  i=complex(imaginary = 1)
  X0=log(S0)
  M=sqrt((rho*sigma*i*u-kappa)^2+sigma^2*(i*u+u^2))
  N=(rho*sigma*i*u-kappa-M)/(rho*sigma*i*u-kappa+M)
  A=(r-q)*i*u*tau+kappa*theta/sigma^2*(-(rho*sigma*i*u-kappa-M)*tau-2*log((1-N*exp(M*tau))/(1-N)))
  B=(exp(M*tau)-1)*(rho*sigma*i*u-kappa-M)/(sigma^2*(1-N*exp(M*tau)))
  return(exp(A+B*V0+i*u*X0))
}

f_2=function(u,r,q,tau,V0,S0,sigma,rho,kappa,theta){
  i=complex(imaginary = 1)
  return(exp(-i*u*log(S0))*exp(-i*u*(r-q)*tau)*f_heston(u,r,q,tau,V0,S0,sigma,rho,kappa,theta))
}

g_heston=function(u,S0,K,r,q,kappa,theta,V0,tau,sigma,rho){
  i=complex(imaginary = 1)
  k=log(S0/K)+(r-q)*tau
  g=Re(exp(-i*u*k)*f_2(-u-i/2,r,q,tau,V0,S0,sigma,rho,kappa,theta))/(u^2+1/4)
  if(is.nan(g)) return(0) else return(g)
}
```

g_heston quickly reaches 0 as it should, but it starts to produce NaN's for large values of u. I tried to counteract this by making the function return 0 if g was a NaN.

```
integrate(g_heston, lower=0, upper= Inf ,S0=100,K=120,r=0.05,q=0.02,kappa=1,theta=1,V0=1,tau=2,sigma=1,rho=-0.3 )
```

This did not remove the error: "non-finite function value", and in addition, the function now also gives warnings:

In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (is.nan(g)) return(0) else return(g) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I don't see how is.nan(g) can have length > 1, why it produces the error (and why the error isn't caught by the stop.on.error condition), and also why g_heston would produce NaNs in the first place.

Comment: You need to use `ifelse` instead of `if` and `else`-

Comment: replacing
    if(is.nan(g)) return(0) else return(g)
with 
    ifelse(is.nan(g),return(0),return(g))
produces the error: "evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length"
when running the integrate line.

Comment: No, remove the `return`s: it should be `ifelse(is.nan(g),0,g)`. You must provide `integrate` with a vectorized function.

Comment: This worked! thank you.